# Send email to confirm registration with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I use FOSUserBundle to perform login/registration on my application.

I want a new user to confirm his email by sending him a confirmation email.

After reading the official documentation and different tutorials i have the same error :

> The check email page appear after i register a user but i don't receive the email.

This is my configurations

```
#config/config.yml


swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

fos_user:
    db_driver:     orm                       
    firewall_name: main                      
    user_class:    VK\UserBundle\Entity\User 
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
            from_email:
                address: my_username@gmail.com
                sender_name: Demo registration
    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
```

And this is my parameters

```
config/parameters.yml

parameters:
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
    mailer_encryption: ssl
    mailer_user: my_username@gmail.com
    mailer_password: my_password
```

Please can some one help me solve this issue ? thank's

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is your `swiftmailer` configuration. Edit your parameters to

```
parameters:
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_host:      ~
    mailer_user:      your_gmail_username
    mailer_password:  your_gmail_password
```

or add `encryption` and `auth_mode` attribute to your actual configuration

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    encryption:"%mailer_encryption%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    auth_mode: "%mailer_auth_mode%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

```
parameters:
    mailer_auth_mode: login
    mailer_encryption: ssl
    mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_user: my_username@gmail.com
    mailer_password: my_password
```

Documentation can be found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html).

Comment: thanks for replying but i got the same error. No email !

Comment: I always redirected to the check email page but i don't receive an email.

Comment: enable the data collector with the attribute `logging: true` on `swiftmailer` configuration, and check your profiler. Then check your `/var/log/maillog` file for errors

Comment: I try it but no email. And i don't have this directory **/var/log/maillog** on my computer

Comment: If you are not using gmail account to send mails, check if you have a mail server configured in your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your gmail?. I just solved my problem. It was

> Access for less secure apps has been turned off

. After turn on I received email.

```
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_auth_mode: login
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: ************
mailer_password: ********
```